# Regular expression to match Url's, except a certain domain

Tags: c#, regex

I have the following regular expression that matches Url's. What I want to do is make it not match when a URL belongs to a certain domain, let's say google.com.

How can I do that? I've been reading other question and regular expression references and so far I could achieve it. My Regular expression:

```
^(https?:\/\/)?([\da-zA-Z\.-]+)\.([a-zA-Z\.]{2,6})([\/\w \.-]*)*\/?$
```

I use this to filter messages in a chat, I'm using C# to do so. Here's a tool in case you want to dig further: http://regexr.com/3faji

C# extension method:

```
static class String
{
    public static string ClearUrl(string text)
    {
        Regex regx = new Regex(@"^(https?:\/\/)?([\da-zA-Z\.-]+)\.([a-zA-Z\.]{2,6})([\/\w \.-]*)*\/?$",
        RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
        string output = regx.Replace(text, "*");

        return output;

    }
}
```

Thanks for any help

Comment: Add a negative lookahead: `^(https?:\/\/)?(?!(?:www\.)?google\.com)([\da-zA-Z.-]+)\.([a-zA-Z\.]{2,6})([\/\w .-]*)*\/?$`

Comment: @anubhava thanks for your comment. The expression you pasted don't work, but now that I know about negative lookahead I will look for it and try to make it work. Thanks

Comment: Provide sample data and your regex language/tool so that we can dig further.

Comment: @anubhava ok, I added to the question

Comment: [You can see, my suggested regex works pretty well](https://regex101.com/r/iZdpZS/1)

Comment: @anubhava it does. I got to this one and it works too: ^(https?:\/\/)?(?!(.*)?google.com)([\da-zA-Z\.-]+)\.([a-zA-Z\.]{2,6})([\/\w \.-]*)*\/?$  but place your answer please so I can mark as correct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use negative lookahead in your regex to avoid matching certain domains:

```
^(https?:\/\/)?(?!(?:www\.)?google\.com)([\da-zA-Z.-]+)\.([a‌​-zA-Z\.]{2,6})([\/\w .-]*)*\/?$
```

Or else:

```
^(https?:\/\/)?(?!.*google\.com)([\da-zA-Z.-]+)\.([a‌​-zA-Z\.]{2,6})([\/\w .-]*)*\/?$
```

`(?!(?:www\.)?google\.com)` is negative lookahead that will assert failure when we have `www.google.com` or `google.com` ahead.

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/iZdpZS/1)

Answer (score 1):

This should work using negative lookahead, and also includes URLs that start with www instead of the protocol, and also that are not the first character of a line:

```
((http|ftp|https):\/\/|www.)(?!google|www.google)[\w\-_]+(\.[\w\-_]+)+([\w\-\.,@?^=%&amp;:/~\+#]*[\w\-\@?^=%&amp;/~\+#])?
```